# Vibration not working on android 4.0

Tags: android, vibration

In my application, Vibration mode not working above 4.0 version?

My code is,

```
 final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)
 this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 vibe.vibrate(800);
```

CAn any please help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance

In manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got this added to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Which device are you testing this on - perhaps it does not support vibration? I recently ran into this issue and it turns out that the Nexus 7 simply [does not have vibration support](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/eyes-free/BTSIphBf7AY).